# Not able to create new table in hive from Spark-shell

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, derby

I am using single node setup in Redhat and installed Hadoop Hive Pig and Spark . I configured hive metadata in Derby and everything . I created new folder for Hive tables and gave full privilege (chmod 777 ) . Then I created one table from Hive CLI and I am able to select those data in Spark-shell and printed those values to the console. But from Spark-shell/Spark-Sql I am not able to create new tables .It is throwing error  as

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:file:/2016/hive/test2 is not a directory or unable to create one)
```

I checked the permission and User(using same user for Installation and Hive and Hadoop Spark etc).
Is there anything need to be done for getting full integration of Spark and Hive

Thanks

Comment: What command did you run from spark shell?

Comment: Spark SQL Create table test(Id int)

Comment: Spark Shell Same query using SqlContext

Answer (score 0):

Check that the permissions *in hdfs* are correct (not just the filesystem)

```
hadoop fs -chmod -R 755 /user
```

If the error message persists afterwards please update the question.